# Autotools: add library globally for multiple targets

Tags: autotools, automake, cunit

My project has the following **Makefile.am** file and it fails to `./configure` because the CUnit function symbols are not found.

```
bin_PROGRAMS = test_one test_two

AM_CFLAGS = -Wall -pedantic -I../src
AM_LDFLAGS = \
    -Wl,-z,relro \
    -Wl,-z,now
AM_LDADD = -lcunit -lmylib

test_one_SOURCES = test_one.c ../src/another.c
test_two_SOURCES = test_two.c ../src/another.c
```

How to add (the CUnit) library globally, once for all targets?

Comment: add `-L/path/to/libCUnit` to `AM_LDFLAGS`

Comment: And where is CUnit installed? What if your project is built on a system where it is *not* installed? Why don't you search for it in your `configure.ac` script?

Comment: Flags like `-L` are ok, they are provided by environment variables at used by `./configure` at runtime. It was just a matter of how to tell automake what I want